# Unexpected error using FINDSTR on cmd and outputting PATH

Tags: findstr

In a script that I write, want to locate C++ functions inside **.cpp** files by calling `findstr` in a python script. I am testing this manually on `cmd` inside the project directory where several **.cpp** and **.h** files are contained.

by using:

```
findstr /spinm /C:"werden oder sollen neue Versionen dieser Dateien angelegt werden?\",Project::Plural())" *.cpp
```

output:

```
target.cpp
```

I get the correct **.cpp** file where the function is contained, let's call it `target.cpp.` . However I am writing this python script so users can later go find changes on certain functions, so I need it should show whole path in the output . In a solution I found on stack overflow I used:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /spinm /C:"werden oder sollen neue Versionen dieser Dateien angelegt werden?\",Project::Plural())" *.cpp') do echo %~fa
```

output:

```
)" *.cpp') do echo %~fa was unexpected at this time.
```

Note that if I use the same command such as:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /spinm /C:"bool" *.cpp') do echo %~fa
```

I get a list of all the **.cpp** along with the full path (what is needed) in that folder and sub directories that use the bool type in them.

Comment: I'm assuming the parenthesis after :  `in (` is terminating at the first closing parenthesis after Plural : `Plural())`. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several hours of brainstorming:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /spinmr /C:"werden oder sollen neue Versionen dieser Dateien angelegt werden?.*,Project::Plural())" *.cpp') do echo %~fa
```

I'm not an expert but when I change my string to an expression using `/R` option in `findstr` and then use **.*** (wildcard character) it works.

Problem was that although `findstr` recognized the **\"** as a quotation character inside the string this creates problems with cmd when I use it in `in(' **findstr command** ')` where 3 quotation marks was expected as an additional string input.